# How to pass alphanumeric variable that contains spaces between 2 functions in bash?

Tags: string, bash, variables, space

Script:

```
function insertMessage {
   $1 > log.txt
}

function checkResult {
  if [ $1 -eq 0 ]; then
    insertMessage "$2"
  else
    insertMessage "$3"
  fi
}
```

But when I try:

```
 rm $DIR
 checkResult $? 'Directory deleted ok' 'Cannot delete directory'
```

I receive only `Directory` in log.txt. Seems that bash consider also spaces in string - so takes as `$2` only word `Directory`.

How it can be resolved? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use quotes:

```
function checkResult {
   if [ "$1" -eq 0 ]; then
     insertMessage "$2"
    else
     insertMessage "$3"
    fi
}
```

And your `insertMessage` function looks strange:

```
function insertMessage {
    echo "$1" >> log.txt
}
```

would make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the $2 and $3 arguments without quoting as Mat has mentioned, hence the `insertMessage` function recieves the following arguments for success in your example:

```
$1 = Directory
$2 = deleted
$3 = ok
```

Thus with `echo $1 > log.txt` you are only going to get 'Directory' in your output.

To echo the entire list of arguments, without quoting the parameters you pass in `checkResult` you could do:

```
function insertMessage {
    echo $@ > log.txt
}
```

Where `$@` is an array of all the parameters passed to the function.